# Dropbox Drop-in file chooser not loading within AjaxForm

Tags: jquery, ajax, dropbox

I am building an input form and the Dropin JS script works great. When I try and load that input form via ajax, the chooser does not show up and I cannot get the magic to happen. Is there any script I need to load after rendering the input form or something that is happening out of order?

When the input form renders, the "Choose a Dropbox File" button does not render at all.

======Element On Form Loaded via AJAX===========

```
<input type="dropbox-chooser" name="selected-file" id="db-chooser" />
```

======JQuery Script that Loads the form=========

```
function addContent(lesson) {
     $.ajax({
         type: 'GET',
         url: "/Content/CreateModal",
         data: {
             'lesson': lesson
         },
         success: function (response) {
            $('#lesson' + lesson).html(response);
            document.getElementById("db-chooser").addEventListener("DbxChooserSuccess",
                            function (e) {
                                $("#DropboxUrl").val(e.files[0].link);
                            }, false);
         }
     });
}
```

Comment: FYI, asked and answered here on the Dropbox developer forum: https://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=107172

Comment: True.  Last time I'd posted on Dropbox forums it sat there stale, today it was answered in minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per @smarx it was answered on the [DB Forum](https://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=107172).

I used the new [Dropbox.choose()](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/dropins/chooser/js) function and replaced the  with

```
<a href="#" onclick="Dropbox.choose({ success: function (files) { $('#Url').val(files[0].link); } });">
  <img src="@Url.Content("~/img/dropbox35.png")" style="width:20px" />
</a>
```

And it works beautifully.